# Error with loading my package in r?

Tags: r

I built my own package and everythings goes well. then when I generate `src` file for `.c` files I got the problem.

```
    1- I used devtools::use_rcpp()
    2- Then create a file to put these lines: #' @useDynLib Mypackage
#' @importFrom Rcpp sourceCpp
NULL
```

Then when I build adn load the package I got this error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Mypackage’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 shared object ‘Mypackage.so’ not found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
```

Note that: my `namespace` files generated automatically by `roxygen2`.

any help please?

I built my package again using the `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` :

I then built my own funciton in R where I call the `.C` file but I got this error.

```
My_func <- function(x){
  x*4
  .Call(rcpp_hello_world,PACKAGE = "Mypackage")[[1]]
}


 > My_func(4)
Error in .Call(rcpp_hello_world, PACKAGE = "MixRVinE") : 
  first argument must be a string (of length 1) or native symbol reference
```

Comment: is your package on github?

Comment: @SymbolixAU No it is not.

Comment: Simplify, simplify, simplify.  Don't use devtools, use the functionality _in the Rcpp package_ ie start with `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`.  Check that the package it created worked.  Then add your code.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I tried it but I cannot call my `.C` files from the other R function.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel if I write R function then add a call line to call my `.c` files it does not work!! that way I tried another way

Comment: If you insist on `.C()` (and you probably should not, everybody recommends `.Call()`) then re-read Writing R Extensions.  You do something wrong _but as you provide no minimal reproducible example_ nobody can help you.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Ok I will try your suggestion and see what I will got and will update my question. Thanks a lot to you.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I built my funciton again and I get the error. Please see the edit of my question

Comment: Well if you now want to use Rcpp I recommend you start by using a complete tutorial. Randomly borrowing single lines will not get you there.

Comment: @I follow your tutorial online and hope I do well